# making two db calls within restdb.io javascript onGET function

Tags: javascript, restdb

In restdb.io I am creating a custom server route https://restdb.io/docs/custom-rest-routes#restdb to select a random document from a collection (rather than returning the whole collection to Bixby, then selecting the random) and I am having some difficulty getting the onGET function to make two database calls in a row.

```
// #!/javascript

const onGET = (req, res) => {
    db.get("/rest/content?totals=true&count=true", {"contenttype": "facts"}, {}, (dberr, dbdata) => {
        //log.debug("Input", req);

        const c = dbdata.totals.count
        log.debug("count is", c)

        // pick random number 1 ... c

        // skip to doc #c and get just one


        // for now just get doc #5

        const test  = "5"
        log.debug("test is", test)
        // command to get doc #5 not working 

        const foo = db.get("/rest/content?skip=5)", {"contenttype": "facts"}, {$max: 1})
        log.debug("foo is", foo)

        res.end({"text": foo});    
    })

}
```

the REST inspector shows the following output:

```
08 Mar 20:31:10 200 GET /rest/content?totals=true&count=true&q={"contenttype":"facts"}&h={} ...
08 Mar 20:31:10 200 DEBUG random2.onGET count is 230
08 Mar 20:31:10 200 DEBUG random2.onGET test is 5
08 Mar 20:31:10 200 DEBUG random2.onGET foo is {}
```

So the problem is that it's not carrying out the second db request and thus the response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this part of the code

```
 log.debug("foo is", foo)

 res.end({"text": foo});
```

part of a *callback*.

Look at the way you are writing `db.get(..., (dberr, dbdata) => { ... }`

the contents in { ... } are your callback function.

So for your second call, (the one made with `const foo`), you must do the same pattern.

For more about callbacks, see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function